# C# "finally" how to write a code for this using simple example?

Tags: c#

I need some help regarding "Finally" Method considering the following simple example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x, y;

    Console.WriteLine("enter a number for x");
    x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("enter a number for y");
    y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x / y);
    }

    catch (DivideByZeroException dz)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dz.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of help do you need?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. What do you need exactly? you can just add `finally{}` after the `catch` block but what's your intention with that `finally` block?

Comment: I suggest looking it up. There are plenty of answers for what `finally` does (and why) on the internet, including [this website](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=finally+c%23).

Comment: @gautham: Then read the language specification.

Comment: finally is used to do a piece of work which shd always be performed irrespective of the exception. In this case if you want you can use a variable to store the result like result = x/y.. in finally you can print it on console.

Comment: sajoshi, thank you but can you post the code if possible?

Comment: @ Anthony Pegram, Jason, lcarus: i tried but i am unable to find simple code so that i can clearly understand its purpose.....

Comment: @gautham: if you insist on learning through sample code, then you will always be behind those who learn by actually reading and understanding. Go right ahead, though, if you insist on remaining a second-class developer.

Comment: @John Saunders: I joined this "Forum" after visiting some sites in "google".... MSDN says: The finally block is useful for cleaning up any resources that are allocated in the try block, and for running any code that must execute even if an exception occurs in the try block.<- but still i am unable to understand its purpose?

Comment: "The finally block is useful for cleaning up any resources that are allocated in the try block"<- 1.What are those "resources", 2. what are getting "allocated", 3. and what it will "clean"?

Comment: This is not a forum. Please read the [faq]. Also, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/z1zx9t92.

Comment: @John Saunders: Thank you very much for your Kind Help and Kind words...

Comment: @gautham - All your questions about the statement is really answered by "it depends" your example code is to simple, so in that case nothing to all of those questions, a finally block in your example code would be pointless.

Comment: @Ramhound: "The finally block is useful for cleaning up any resources that are allocated in the try block"<- 1.What are those "resources", 2. what are getting "allocated", 3. and what it will "clean"?

Answer (score 1):

`finally` does what it sounds like it should, it always runs, regardless if there is an exception, or even an exception handling the exception.  It's used primarily to ensure that a shared or system resource is cleaned up correctly.

```
bool successful = true;
try{
    // Do Some Work
    Foo();
} catch { 
    successful = false;
    throw;
} finally {
    if(successful){
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
    }else {
        Console.WriteLine("Unsuccessful");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is showing "Foo();" as error!

Comment: @gautham Foo() is just a dummy method.  You can replace it with 10/(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); to get an idea.  Enter 0 or "abc" and it throws your exception, but the unsuccessful still gets outputted.

Comment: @gautham You can't do it in a comment, only if you're editing you're question, or providing an answer.

Comment: @gautham - If you have additional questions post a new question this one is locked.  Some advice remove your rude comment from your profile.  You won't get help from me unless you do.